# SP2013 Access denied on mobile view

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I'm having a strange issue with my mobile view.

I have created a custom permissions level to be used in this list (Basically it's just edit without delete). When the users are editing the items in the list in desktop mode everything is working as intended.

However, when the users tries to do the same on their mobile, they get an "Access denied".

What have I overlooked?

Comment: Do you have custom files which users have permissions to read, or is the files (css and JavaScript) in a published version?

Comment: No it's just a normal list item - and like i said they can open it in desktop view (Even on their phone) - it's just for the mobile view the access is denied.

Comment: Are they logged in to the company network using company WiFi which has access to AD?

Comment: Both - however it cannot be related to that as it works for them when they use the same mobile device (On or off the company wifi) but in desktop view.